# useEffect infinite loop even though I've provided a dependency list

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to create a query page using redux, axios and an API. In `useEffect()`, if the variable from the `useSelector` is empty and the `isLoading` state is `false`, then I do the API request. However even without any changes to these variables (already in the dependency list), the `useEffect` keeps firing the API request indefinitely).

And while inspecting the state, I see `integrationStatusLoading` changing from `true` to `false` all the time. It seems that the `useEffect` is fired several times even before having completed the previous run.

My reducer:

```
import * as spreadsheetActions from './spreadsheetActions';

export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  messagesLog: [],
  loading: false,
  modalIsOpen: false,
  integration: {
    rows: [],
    loading: false
  }
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case spreadsheetActions.SET_INTEGRATION_STATUS:
      return { ...state, integration: {
        ...state.integration,
        rows: action.payload
      }};
    case spreadsheetActions.SET_LOADING_INTEGRATION_STATUS:
      return { ...state, integration: {
        ...state.integration,
        loading: action.payload
      }};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The jsx:

```
  const IntegrationStatusContainer = function() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const integrationStatusData = useSelector(state => state.spreadsheet.integration.rows);
  const integrationStatusLoading = useSelector(state => state.spreadsheet.integration.loading);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isEmpty(integrationStatusData) && !integrationStatusLoading) {
      dispatch(spreadsheetOperations.getIntegrationStatus());
    }
  }, [dispatch, integrationStatusData, integrationStatusLoading]);

  return (
    <IntegrationStatusTable items={integrationStatusData} isLoading={integrationStatusLoading} />
  );
};

export default IntegrationStatusContainer;
```

spreadsheetOperations.js

```
export const getIntegrationStatus = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(spreadsheetActions.setLoadingIntegrationStatus(true));

  let response = await spreadsheetManager.getIntegrationStatus();

  batch(() => {
    dispatch(spreadsheetActions.setLoadingIntegrationStatus(false));
    dispatch(spreadsheetActions.setIntegrationStatus(response));
  });
};
```

spreadsheetManager.js

```
getIntegrationStatus = async () => {
    const getIntegrationStatusResult = await spreadsheetService.getIntegrationStatus();
    return getIntegrationStatusResult;
  };
```

spreadsheetService.js

```
getIntegrationStatus = async () => {
    const integrationStatusResponse = await axios.get(
      `${BASE_URL}/api/integration_status`
    );
    return integrationStatusResponse.data;
  };
}
```

spreadsheetActions.js

```
export const setIntegrationStatus = rows => ({
  type: SET_INTEGRATION_STATUS,
  payload: rows
});

export const setLoadingIntegrationStatus = status => ({
  type: SET_LOADING_INTEGRATION_STATUS,
  payload: status
});
```

What is wrong with my code? How can I stop the infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by creating a new `fetchStatus` state with three possible values (pending, fulfilled and rejected), then in my if I've added a condition checking for `fetchStatus === 'pending'`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are replying on isEmpty to check whether API should be called. Can you check if isEmpty is working as expected or the API is always returning empty response?

Comment: Currently the API always returns an empty array, but that's because there are no rows in database.

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected functionality of this component? That the API call only fires once?

Your store updates to the isLoading flag will cause a render every time it changes. At the moment your cycle looks like it would be:

- Initial render - **fire API call**
- Render from flag changing to true
- Render from flag changing to false - **fire API call**
- **Repeat step 2 and 3 indefinitely**

Have you console logged the variables inside the effect as well as the redux state? If the Redux state is changing then it **will** fire a render on the component.

I think the simplest solution is to remove the isLoading flag from the dependancies, unless you have a retry scenario you're trying to achieve but I'd be looking at redux-saga for a solution to that.

Comment: Exactly. I want it to fire just once. I tried the empty array (`[]`) in the dependency list, however React complains about this and tells that I need to put `dispatch` and those variables there. And yes, I've console logged and the `integrationStatusLoading` keeps changing.

Comment: I think you just need to bin that dependancy list. Ideally all of it, but I've not really used the react hooks stuff before and maybe you need to keep dispatch in there. Certainly having the isLoading flag will just keep hammering it! Can you post what happens when you remove all dependancies except dispatch?